# How to conditionally remove quotes in write.csv?

Tags: r, csv

When using `write.csv`, one may reduce file sizes significantly (approx 25% for large datasets) by removing quotes using `quote=FALSE`. However, this may cause `read.csv` to malfunction if commas are present in your data. For example:

```
x <- data.frame(a=1:2,b=c("hello,","world"))
dim(x)
[1] 2 2
f <- tempfile()
write.csv(x,f,row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
dim(read.csv(f))
[1] 2 2
read.csv(f)
      a  b
1 hello NA
2 world NA
```

Observe column name misalignment and a loss of data and addition of spurious data.

Is is possible to remove quotes generally, but maintain them for fields that have commas in  the data?

Comment: [The docs](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html) seem to say that this is not possible, unless you know in advance which columns to quote ("If [`quote` is] a numeric vector, its elements are taken as the indices of columns to quote."). Other languages offer a "quote only when necessary" option which R doesn't appear to have. Perhaps you could post-process your files with such a language (like Python)?

Comment: or something like `which(sapply(mydata,function(x) (is.factor(x) || is.character(x)) && any(grepl(","x)))` to figure out which columns need to be protected?

Comment: @TimPietzcker As you supsected, it looks like there is no inbuilt way to quote when necessary, but I used your suggestions to quote only the columns affected. If either of you want to write up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I went with was a combination of the comments of @TimPietzcker and @BenBolker.

`quote` can be a numeric vector to specify which columns get quoted. While I would have preferred to only quote when needed, this allowed almost the full file-size reduction in my case (also using `na=""`).

```
commas <- which(sapply(x, function(y) any(grepl(",",y))))
write.csv(x,f,row.names=FALSE,quote=commas)
read.csv(f)
  a      b
1 1 hello,
2 2  world
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my implementation of the idea that @Bill Denney suggested. I think it is nicer partly because it is briefer and more understandable to me, but mostly because I wrote it :)

```
##' Write CSV files with quotes same as MS Excel 2013 or newer
##'
##' R inserts quotes where MS EExcel CSV export no longer inserts quotation marks on character
##' variables, except when the cells include commas or quotation marks.
##' This function generates CSV files that are, so far as we know
##' in exactly the same style as MS Excel CSV export files.
##'
##' This works by manually inserting quotation marks where necessary and
##' turning FALSE R's own method to insert quotation marks.
##' @param x a data frame
##' @param file character string for file name
##' @param row.names Default FALSE for row.names
##' @return the return from write.table.
##' @author Paul Johnson
##' @examples
##' set.seed(234)
##' x1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b,c", "b", "The \"Washington, DC\""),
##'       x2 = rnorm(4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
##' x1
##' dn <- tempdir()
##' fn <- tempfile(pattern = "testcsv", fileext = ".csv")
##' writeCSV(x1, file = fn)
##' readLines(fn)
##' x2 <- read.table(fn, sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
##' all.equal(x1,x2)
writeCSV <- function(x, file, row.names = FALSE){
    xischar <- colnames(x)[sapply(x, is.character)]
    for(jj in xischar){
        x[ , jj] <- gsub('"', '""', x[ , jj], fixed = TRUE)
        needsquotes <- grep('[\",]', x[ ,jj])
        x[needsquotes, jj] <- paste0("\"", x[needsquotes, jj], "\"")
    }
    write.table(x, file = file, sep = ",", quote = FALSE,
                row.names = row.names)
}
```

Output from the example:

```
>  set.seed(234)
>  x1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b,c", "b", "The \"Washington, DC\""),
+        x2 = rnorm(4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
>  x1
                    x1         x2
1                    a  0.6607697
2                  b,c -2.0529830
3                    b -1.4992061
4 The "Washington, DC"  1.4712331
>  dn <- tempdir()
>  fn <- tempfile(pattern = "testcsv", fileext = ".csv")
>  writeCSV(x1, file = fn)
>  readLines(fn)
[1] "x1,x2"                                         
[2] "a,0.660769736644892"                           
[3] "\"b,c\",-2.052983003941"                       
[4] "b,-1.49920605110092"                           
[5] "\"The \"\"Washington, DC\"\"\",1.4712331168047"
>  x2 <- read.table(fn, sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
>  all.equal(x1,x2)
[1] TRUE
>
```

Comment: At a glance, your function looks good.  My thoughts are:1) What about types other than characters and numbers?  Many types (factors, Date, etc.) could also contain commas or quotes.  2) It doesn't generalize to other separators, quote methods, end of line markers, etc. (This probably doesn't matter for your use case, but I need to have them because I sometimes generate tab separated value files that also benefit from minimal quoting.) 3) What about internationalization (including alternate decimal places as commas)?

Comment: Rather than a for loop, use lapply to create the modified strings. Indexing a data frame with `[` can be bog-slow.

Answer (score 2):

In case others are looking for a similar solution, I just wrote a comprehensive replacement of `write.csv` (`write.csv.minimal.quote`) that only quotes when absolutely required:

```
quote.if.required <- function(x, qmethod=c("double", "escape"), sep=",", eol="\n") {
  qmethod <- match.arg(qmethod)
  x <- as.character(x)
  mask.quote.sub <- grepl('"', x, fixed=TRUE)
  mask.quote.sep <-
    grepl(sep, x, fixed=TRUE) |
    grepl(eol, x, fixed=TRUE)
  qstring <- switch(qmethod, escape="\\\\\"", double="\"\"")
  x[mask.quote.sub] <-
    paste0('"', gsub('"', qstring, x[mask.quote.sub]), '"')
  x[mask.quote.sep & !mask.quote.sub] <-
    paste0('"', x[mask.quote.sep & !mask.quote.sub], '"')
  x
}

write.csv.minimal.quote <- function(x, file="", ..., qmethod=c("double", "escape"), row.names=FALSE, sep=",", eol="\n", quote) {
  qmethod <- match.arg(qmethod)
  if (!is.data.frame(x)) {
    cn <- colnames(x)
    x <- as.data.frame(x)
    colnames(x) <- cn
  } else {
    cn <- colnames(x)
  }
  cn <- quote.if.required(cn,
                          qmethod=qmethod,
                          sep=sep,
                          eol=eol)
  x <- as.data.frame(lapply(x, quote.if.required,
                            qmethod=qmethod,
                            sep=sep,
                            eol=eol))
  if (is.logical(row.names) && row.names) {
    row.names <- quote.if.required(base::row.names(x),
                                   qmethod=qmethod,
                                   sep=sep,
                                   eol=eol)
  } else if (is.character(row.names)) {
    row.names <- quote.if.required(row.names,
                                   qmethod=qmethod,
                                   sep=sep,
                                   eol=eol)
  }

  write.table(x, file=file, append=FALSE, sep=",", dec=".", eol="\n", col.names=cn, row.names=row.names, quote=FALSE)
}

#tmp <- data.frame('"abc'=1:3, "def,hij"=c("1,2", "3", '4"5'), klm=6:8)
#names(tmp) <- c('"abc', "def,hij", "klm")
#write.csv.minimal.quote(tmp, file="test.csv")
```

Comment: This is the correct way to go. Recently we have problem that csv from R is rejected by importers that have adapted to the way MS Excel does this. Since MS Excel changed the way they do quotation marks, it has been a constant PITA. I'm going to see if I can shorten this down a bit and discuss with some R insiders.  I believe R's write.table need a quote argument "msexcel" or similar to produce the MS behavior.

Comment: Just posted my own R function to do same. Could use your stress testing.

Comment: For others who find this, it looks like `readr::write_csv()` implements minimal quoting.

Answer (score 1):

If the value contains a comma wrap it in quotes.  Then `write.csv` with `quote = FALSE`.

```
library(stringr)
options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)

d <- data.frame(
  x = c("no comma", "has,comma")
)

d$x <- with(d, ifelse(str_detect(x, ","), dQuote(x), as.character(x)))

filename <- "test.csv"
write.csv(d, file = filename, quote = FALSE, row.names= FALSE)
noquote(readLines(filename))
## [1] x           no comma    "has,comma"
read.csv(filename)
##           x
## 1  no comma
## 2 has,comma
```

(You can substitute `grepl` for `str_detect`, and `paste` for `dQuote` if you prefer.)

---

On the other hand, I don't believe that for most datasets you will get anywhere near 25% file size saving.  If small files are your goal, then you would do better to compress your file (see `zip` and `tar` in the `utils` package), or store it in a binary file (see `save` and the `rhdf5` package), or maybe in a database.

Comment: Thanks, this does what I was thinking, but quite fiddly for a large number of cols. I took the advice in the comments and just quoted the entire columns affected by specifying to `quote`. The file size reduction was almost as much. The 25% was a bit misleading - it was in conjunction with `na=""`, but was still at least 20% on its own with my data.

Comment: Have you considered just doing `write.csv(..., quote = FALSE, sep = "|")`, or similar?  If you can find a separation character that doesn't appear in your text, the problem goes away.

Comment: Now I think about it, that's pretty much the reason that tab delimited files exist.

Comment: That would be an option, but the trouble is I can't always be sure what will be in my data (there are some free text fields). I also have to communicate it with others and need to keep things as simple and uniform as possible.