# Why does my file size almost double when using write.csv

Tags: r

I recently started working with R for data manipulation.
I'm using R to update some files every month, which means reading them in (I use fread), doing some manipulations and writing them out. The manipulation basically consists of appending a few rows to my dataframe. The number of rows appended is only a small percentage of what is already in the dataframe (say 0,1%).

While I'm appending only a small additional number of rows, I'm noticing that my file sizes are doubling after being written out. (from 1GB to 2 GB, 2GB to 4GB and so on)

Of course, this is not sustainable, so I'm trying to find out what may be causing this. Hope someone can help me.

This is what the code looks like:

```
File <- fread("FileName", data.table = F)
ExtraFile1 <- fread("FileName2")
ExtraFile2 <- fread("FileName3")
newFile <- rbind(File, ExtraFile1,ExtraFile2)
write.csv(newFile,"FileName _ Updated" , row.names = FALSE)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you are not appending to the existing file?   Without a code sample of what you are doing, any answer is just a guess.

Comment: If you have a number of empty cells, these may be replaced by cells with empty strings when saving. You can set `quote=FALSE` to fix, but there may be other complications: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25743018/269476

Comment: @Dave2e I edited my post to give an idea of the code

Comment: @James That seemed to do the trick. Thanks a lot!